# Python 2.7 Word Guessing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I’m trying to write a guessing word program in Python 2.7. The user has 50 chances to correctly guess the word. I’ve already written a function that generates a random word from a list of words. The user needs to correctly guess the word.

For example, if the correct word is “dog” and the user guesses “apple,” the program will return “too low” and the user will then guess again. If the user guesses “pear,” the program will return “too high.”

I don’t really know how to start writing this piece of code. I tried using a while loop, but I don’t know where to go from here. Thank you all in advance.

Here’s what I have so far:

**Note: ‘correct’ is the word the user is trying to guess; guess is the word the user guessed**

```
while guess != 'correct':
    if guess < correct:
        print 'Too low'
        guess = int(raw_input('Enter a word')
    elif guess > correct:
        print 'Too high'
        guess = int(raw_input('Enter a word')
    else:
        print 'You finally got it!'
        break
    print

while tries < 50:
    guess = raw_input('Guess a word')
    if guess not in word: 
        print "Sorry, try again."
    else:
        print 'Good job!'
else:
    print "Sorry. My word was ", word, ". Better luck next time!"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by comparing words with each other as "too high" or "too low"

Comment: Don't put your code in images

Comment: Hi Austin. I understand how that can be confusing. By “too high,” I mean the word is past the correct word in the alphabet. So if the correct word (the one I’m trying to guess) is “cat” and the user guesses “apple,” the program would return “too high,” because “c” comes after “a” and is too “high.” Does that make more sense?

Comment: Forget python and programming at all for a second - go back to plain old english. What exactly do you want your application to do? Why is apple less than dog, why is pear more than dog? Try to break down your goal into a series of very discrete steps. Why is dog more than apple, but less than pear?

Comment: In python, you can grab the ASCII value of a character by using `ord()`.

Comment: I doubt that `guess = int(raw_input('Enter a word')` will produce expected results - you'll probably get an error here most of the time as the interpreter will try to convert the word into integer. Check [int() doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) for more details.

Comment: Why are you using Python 2.7?

Answer (score 2):

there is no need for 2 loops. You can use the **AND** this will stop your loop if a person guessed the word right or if that person run out of lives. Also there is no need to say **int()** for your input as you only input a word. If the word is "too low" you print it decrease lives and enter a new word, similarly for "too high". You stop when your lives are at 0 or you guessed the word

```
guess = raw_input('Guess a word: ')
correct = 'dog'
lives = 50

while guess != correct and lives != 0:
    if guess < correct:
        print 'Too low'
        lives -= 1
        guess = raw_input('Enter a word: ')
    else:
        print 'Too high'
        lives -= 1
        guess = raw_input('Enter a word: ')


if lives == 0 and guess != correct:
    print "Sorry. My word was", correct,". Better luck next time!"
else:
    print "You finally got it!"
```

Comment: There is an edge case in your code that even if they guess the correct word on the last loop they will still get the "sorry" message. Easy fix is to change `if lives == 0` to `if lives == 0 and guess != correct`

Answer (score 2):

I like [OmO Walker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46820281/2990052) to the question. Here is a slight variation of OmO's code.

```
# I like adding a .lower() so the person doesn't have to worry about the case matching.
correct = 'dog'.lower()
lives = 2

guess = None

# I like doing a > check not an != because stuff happens and if lives become < 0 you
# get stuck in an infinite loop. BUT in some cases comparisons <, > can be slower than ==.
# So if speed is a problem stick to ==
while not guess == correct and not lives <= 0:
    # Moving this here makes it so there are fewer places you have to get input.

    # Prints how many lives the user has left.
    print "{} lives remaining".format()
    guess = raw_input('Guess a word: ').lower()

    if guess < correct:
        print '{} was too low'.format(guess)
    elif guess > correct:
        print '{} was too high'.format(guess)
    lives -= 1

if not lives > 0 and not guess == correct:
    # I like using the format string method instead of adding strings or using ',' in a print. It is more reliable if
    # the variable you are trying to print is not a string.
    print "Sorry. My word was {}. Better luck next time!".format(correct)

# Makes sure the guess is really right before giving the confirmation
elif guess == correct:
    print "You got it! The word was {}".format(correct)

# This is an added safety that will be triggered if some how the other conditions fall through. Its better to
# have an error thrown than have a program silently break.
else:
    print "ERROR. Something is broken"
```

Comment: Definitely a better code, all I did was play with @hashicode code, therefore it's easier for him to understand. I really like the formating in your code, makes things look nice

Comment: Thank you all so much, that definitely makes more sense. Is there anyway to track how many “lives” I’ve used?

Comment: the `lives` variable is keeping track of how many lives you have left. Every time the user is offered a guess one is subtracted from the variable until `lives` is <= 0. If you want the user to be able to see how many lives they have left you can add `print "{} lives remaining".format()` before the `guess = raw_input('Guess a word: ').lower()` line. I changed my answer to reflect this.